# ng-include working with .html but not .php

Tags: php, angularjs

I couldn't find any reference that ng-include would not work with a php file however when I changed my .html file to .php the include no longer works and I see `<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->` in the inspector.

The code:
I basically have a series of tabs and I'm using ng-include to fill the content of the tab.  The other tabs work fine and this tab worked fine when including html...

Does not work:

```
          <tab heading="Employees" ng-controller="employeeListCtrl" >

               <div  class="mainView">
                          <!-- filename is emptable.php -->
                         <ng-include src="'views/emptable.php'"></ng-include>
               </div>


          </tab>
```

Works:

```
         <tab heading="Employees" ng-controller="employeeListCtrl" >

               <div  class="mainView">
                          <!-- filename is emptable.html -->
                         <ng-include src="'views/emptable.html'"></ng-include>
               </div>


          </tab>
```

Also Works:

```
       <tab heading="Employees" ng-controller="employeeListCtrl" >

               <div  class="mainView">
                          <!-- filename is emptable.php -->
                         <?php include ('views/emptable.php'); ?>
               </div>


          </tab>
```

I also tried having both emptable.php and emptable.html in the same folder to see if there was some weird way that it was still trying to reference the old file after I renamed it.

any ideas?  thanks.

PS.  I didn't want to use the php include() so to maintain constancy throughout the app.  PHP is managing my backend and server-side stuff, but I was trying to keep all front-end stuff with angularjs /html

** just tried creating a new test php file and added a new ng-include to reference it and it worked fine. it seems to be only that one file.

**update thanks to comments below** I believe it has something to do with ng-include not passing data for the included file.  In my main php file (the one with the tabs) I'm including a user class that allows me to access information about the logged in user.  Then in the php file I'm including I'm using `user->data()->employeeID` to access information about the user.
The php error I get returned is " Call to a member function data() on a non-object"  which I take to show that the included file does not have access to my included User class created in my main php file.  Correct?

Comment: could you try like this ? `<div ng-include="'views/emptable.php'"></div>`

Comment: Can your check your network tab? Is browser firing any XHR to load your PHP file? If yes then what is the response from server?

Comment: thanks for the replies. I didn't even think to check the network (Still learning how angular handles everything).  Sure enough there was a 500 error and it lead me to some code it didn't like in my php file.  
particularly where I have ```ng-click="open(item.employeeID, <?php echo $user->data()->employeeID ?>)" ><?php echo $user->data()->employeeID ?>``` on a button.

is it weird that the php include() was ok with this and angular is not? does it have to do with the fact that ng-include is an ajax call?

Comment: oh. wasn't trying to ignore you @NarekMamikonyan , obviously since I was getting a 500 on the ng-include request, moving the ng-include inside the div tag didn't work either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using PHP data and templates instead of Angular?

Comment: It seems the problem is not the angular thing, its has a PHP reason, yes ?

Comment: @Rob - PHP is handling my backend with my users, authentication, and database connections. In the included file I'm accessing the ID of the currently logged-in user.

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan - yes and no.  It's not really an error in php, it's something in the way Angularjs handles the ng-include XHR calls.  It doesn't seem to include them in the page the same way a server-side include would. (should I close this question and ask a new one if I can't find the info I need)

Comment: @Andy, correct, so you could use a Angular service and $http.get() to pull your users to pass to $scope.users and eliminate PHP all together in your templates.

Comment: @Rob - yes.  After you made me question myself, I'm working on that right now.  I've always been a php guy and don't like changing things up, but I'm trying to push myself with this.

Comment: @Andy, I am also a PHP guy and I've been working with AngularJS for well over a year now and learning to separate your server(PHP) from your client(AngularJS) will provide you with a much nicer development process and will keep your PHP code lean and clean.

Comment: ok. so this question is over but no one posted any answers below.  How can I give you guys some +rep for helping me figure this out.

Comment: @Andy, I added an answer.  Glad to help and hope this improves your development down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AngularJS $http requests to get your PHP data to assign to AngularJS models and apply the models to html views instead of PHP templates.

Comment: Possibly an example would help like jsfiddle

Comment: Which one is more efficient - using ajax or not ?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being because I was trying access PHP objects created in my main php file.  Since the ng-include is an XHR call, it doesn't automatically pass my php Object to the included page.
To correct this, I needed to make an $http.get request within my included html file to pull my php info (in this case to pull the the information about the logged in user).

Comment: Possibly an example would help